# unidentified struct _WS_ERROR

Tags: c++, web-services

I am setting up a web service in C++ using the WSUtil.

I have run the utility on my code and have the generated files.  When I try to build the exe I get the build error:

> 'theerror' uses undefined struct '_WS_ERROR'

from the line:

> WS_ERROR theerror;

In WebServices.h

> typedef struct _WS_ERROR WS_ERROR;

But the definition of _WS_ERROR seems to be causing an issue.  Has anyone had this issue or have any advice on how to find the definition of _WS_ERROR?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but just in case the answer helps someone else:

You aren't supposed to create an WS_ERROR instance yourself.  You should have it allocated for you via [WsCreateError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430497(v=vs.85).aspx).

So:

```
WS_ERROR theerror;
```

Should instead be:

```
WS_ERROR *theError;
HRESULT hr = WsCreateError(NULL, 0, &theError); 
if (FAILED(hr)) { 
 // do appropriate error handling here 
}
```

Don't forget when you are done to:

```
if (theError)
{
  WsFreeError(theError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it will help someone.